# Linq to SQL Add object with child objects

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table "Claim" with a connection to "MobClaim". A "Claim" can have 0 or 1 "MobClaims". I can't seem to figure out how to insert a "Claim" while at the same time inserting a "MobClaim" using Linq to SQL.

```
 Dim newClaim As New Claim With {.ClaimTypeId = 1,
                                 .DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                 .ClaimStatusId = 2
                                }
 Dim newMobClaim = New MobClaim() With {.AccountNumber = data.AccountNumber}
```

Both tables have IDENTITY(1,1) on their primary keys, so the database generates thier ids. MobClaimId (primary key) is connected to DataId (foreign key) on Claim. When I try to add an MobClaim to the MobClaims collection on a Claim, I get one error; when I try to add the MobClaim separately and then update the DataId on the Claim, I get a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I ended up doing was changing the tables...

What I was trying to do was this:

Use a Claim.DataId -> MobClaim.MobClaimId (primary) relationship.

I changed it to:

A Claim.ClaimId (primary) -> MobClaim.ClaimId relationship.

And now it works like this:

```
 Dim newClaim As New Claim With {.ClaimTypeId = 1,
                                 .DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                 .CreatedBy = 3,
                                 .ClaimStatusId = 4
                                 }
 newClaim.MobClaims.Add(New MobClaim() With {.AccountNumber = data.AccountNumber})

 Using service As New ClaimsService
     service.SaveClaim(newClaim) 'InsertOnSubmit/SaveChanges etc...
 End Using
```

It has to be something about how the relationships are set up and how you can add stuff. You might HAVE to use the primary key on the parent table and link to a foreign key on the child table - I was pretty much doing the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

First insert the one with the primary key, then set the foreign key on the other record to the auto-generated primary key.

```
Using dc As New YourLinq2SqlDataContext()

    Dim newMobClaim = New MobClaim() With
        {
            .AccountNumber = Data.AccountNumber
        }
    dc.MobClaims.InsertOnSubmit(newMobClaim)
    dc.SubmitChanges()

    Dim newClaim As New Claim With
        {
            .ClaimTypeId = 1,
            .DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            .ClaimStatusId = 2,
            .DataId = newMobClaim.MobClaimId
        }
    dc.Claims.InsertOnSubmit(newClaim)
    dc.SubmitChanges()

End Using
```

Comment: I tried this, but probably because of the columns/keys I was trying to use, it didn't work.